# How to get the getArguments data from a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am using a fragment for my application.and I also add a bundle into my fragments but when I want to get the added String from the bundle the compiler shows me a null pointer error  like as follows

```
Process: com.softmaker.gazi_opu.personalhealthcare, PID: 3253
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
            at com.softmaker.gazi_opu.personalhealthcare.fragment.GeneralInformationFragment.setValue(GeneralInformationFragment.java:67)
            at com.softmaker.gazi_opu.personalhealthcare.fragment.GeneralInformationFragment.onCreateView(GeneralInformationFragment.java:59)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And my added code and getting the added data code are given bellow

```
public static GeneralInformationFragment getInstance(String profileID){
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("profileId",profileID);
        GeneralInformationFragment generalFragment = new GeneralInformationFragment();
        generalFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return generalFragment;
    }
```

Now for getting data from the this fragment within onCreateMethod

```
String id = getArguments().getString("profileId");
        Log.e("ID :", "" + id.toString());
```

Can anyone suggest me. where am I making mistake ?

Comment: check profileID value , it is may be null

Comment: check getArguments()!=null in your onCreateView your code seem's Ok

Comment: Also as you can see in my answer it's recommend to use 'final_statics_String' for static methods.

Comment: yes brother, I check profileID value it's null ... that's why I am facing problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always pass data like this and work perfectly :

```
public class CategoryResultFragment extends BaseListFragment {

    private static final String CATEGORY_ID = "EXTRA_CATEGORY_ID";
    private static final String CATEGORY_SLUG = "EXTRA_CATEGORY_SLUG";

    private String mCategoryId;
    private String mCategorySlug;

    public static CategoryResultFragment newInstance(String categoryId, String categorySlug) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(CATEGORY_ID, categoryId);
        bundle.putString(CATEGORY_SLUG, categorySlug);
        CategoryResultFragment categoryResultFragment = new CategoryResultFragment();
        categoryResultFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return categoryResultFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mCategoryId = getArguments().getString(CATEGORY_ID);
            mCategorySlug = getArguments().getString(CATEGORY_SLUG);
        }
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: yea it's a good way I think ... but If I want to call this fragment from another activity like 
CategoryResultFragment(getIntent().getStringExtra("CATEGRY_ID"),getIntent.getStringExtra("CATEGORY_SLUG"));
then what value will be return by CATEGORY_ID and CATEGORY_SLUG?? or how can I pass value into this fragment as parameter

Answer (score 0):

always Check for null before converting to String

```
String id = getArguments().getString("profileId");
if(id!=null){
  Log.e("ID :", "" + id.toString());
}
```

Comment: isn't it for just checking problem!!!! dear, I just wanted to know. Am I added the bundle string properly or not.If properly then why this error. and If not then what is the mistake....

Comment: String getting in "id" must be null and you are trying to toString operation on that.

Comment: suppose that , I am only use the id then??